# How to change Vuze download directory?

Tags: configuration, directory, default-programs, bittorrent, vuze

How to make Vuze my default bittorrent program instead of Transmission and change its default download directory?

Answer (score 1):

To make Vuze the default bittorrent program, download a torrent file, right click on it, and choose open with.  You will then get a window like the image below.  Choose Vuse, from the list, and place a check mark in the ***set selected application as default action for this type***

[image]

To change the default download (save) directory go to: Tools --> Options --> Torrents, and change the save directory

[image]

Comment: in **4.3.0.6** version its's on `Tools >> Options >> Files`